# access data in sharded JSON files on S3 from Blaze

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, blaze, odo

I am trying to access line delimited JSON data on S3.
From my understanding of the docs I should be able to do something like

```
print data(S3(Chunks(JSONLines))('s3://KEY:SECRET@bucket/dir/part-*.json').peek()
```

which throws

```
BotoClientError: BotoClientError: Bucket names cannot contain upper-case characters when using either the sub-domain or virtual hosting calling format.
```

I have tried variations on this leading to different errors.

I can get the following to work with local files:

```
print data(chunks(JSONLines)(map(JSONLines, glob("/home/me/data/*")))).peek()
```

I am not really sure why the `(map(JSONLines, glob(` is needed, though.

I do not really understand how to work with [type-modofiers](http://odo.pydata.org/en/latest/type-modifiers.html)

Comment: What other errors do you get? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey @DanielMahler, I was wondering, did my answer helped you?

Answer (score 1):

In the comments section of the *Example 6* from this page http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/51587/boto.exception.BotoClientError states that:

> Bucket names must not contain uppercase characters. We check for
>       this by appending a lowercase character and testing with islower().
>       Note this also covers cases like numeric bucket names with dashes.

the function in use for this evaluation is `check_lowercase_bucketname(n)`
and by the example calls we get:

```
>>> check_lowercase_bucketname("Aaaa")
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
BotoClientError: S3Error: Bucket names cannot contain upper-case
characters when using either the sub-domain or virtual hosting calling
format.

>>> check_lowercase_bucketname("1234-5678-9123")
True
>>> check_lowercase_bucketname("abcdefg1234")
True
```

The above mentioned, lead me to believe that your call to `'s3://KEY:SECRET@bucket/dir/part-*.json'` does not pass because either the **KEY** and/or the **SECRET** variables contain UpperCase or disallowed characters